# Chrome fetch API not working when base url changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

I have a web app running on http://localhost:8000

I'm making the following request to a backend service using the fetch api

```
 fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/", {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        "some": "data",
      }
    })
```

On the server I have setup logging. I can see that the content-type is not being set to application/json.

I believe it has some relationship to the base URL. When I set the URL to http://localhost:8000, in the network tab of chrome dev tools I see the request go out with content-type application/json. When the port is changed to 1337, I don't see content-type set.

What am I don't wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you take into account the [Same-origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)? I.e.: You need to deliver your page with the same port as you make you request to or you need to whitelist the other ports. Different port also means different origin. Otherwise your browser is likely not to perform the call. Did you check the error console?

Comment: OPTIONS http://localhost:1337/api/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - not a very useful output on console ... but i would also guess it is some rule like that is at the root of this.  Its only for localhost testing I need this ... so question is, how do i get around the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Some Googling later. I need to start chrome from the CLI and disable web security

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

Thanks @Psi for the tip on [Same-origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: You can configure your website to allow (whitelist) the url with port 1337 as you can read in the specs of the sop